# Tikz, coordinate by trig functions

Tags: tikz-pgf

quick question:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw  (0,0) grid (4,2);
\fill[red] (canvas cs:x=1cm,y={sin(120)}) circle (2pt);
\fill[green] (canvas cs:x=2cm,y={sin(45)}) circle (2pt);
\fill[blue] (canvas cs:x=3cm,y=-{sin(30)}) circle (2pt);
\fill[black] (canvas cs:x=4cm,y=5mm+{sin(30)}) circle (2pt); << it does not work
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How do I insert a trig function within a coordinate calculation, as above last line?

[image]

Comment: The nodes are exactly where they are supposed to be. e.g. sin(30) is 0.5, which would be 0.5cm, adding 5mm yields 1cm and that's where the black node is placed.

Comment: @clocktown Forget my edit. How do I make tiles 1cmx1cm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\fill[black] (canvas cs:x=4cm,y={5mm+sin(30)}) circle (2pt);
```

You basically just have to move that one `{` to the left a bit.
TikZ Syntax can be quite tricky sometimes.

Edit:
The result of these sinus-calculations for `y` seem to be in a weird unit, at least not a metric one it seems. I always thought `cm` would be default, but that assumption seems to be wrong here. I'm guessing it's something like `pt` here. Thus I'd suggest:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw  (0,0) grid (4,2);
\fill[red] (canvas cs:x=1cm,y={1cm*sin(120)}) circle (2pt);
\fill[green] (canvas cs:x=2cm,y={1cm*sin(45)}) circle (2pt);
\fill[blue] (canvas cs:x=3cm,y=-{1cm*sin(30)}) circle (2pt);
\fill[black] (canvas cs:x=4cm,y={5mm+1cm*sin(30)}) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

`1cm*` converts it into cm, so you can change it to whatever unit you want.

Comment: @ clocktown Thks, look at it tomorrow.

Comment: @ clocktown  See new image, it seems that `1cm*sin(120)` returns `1cm`  plus `sin(120)`. Is that intended?

Comment: It's most likely not a weird unit, but points (1 pt = 1/72.27 in). It appears that if no unit is given, then points are used, try for example `\fill[red] (canvas cs:x=1cm,y=28.45) circle (2pt);
\fill[green] (canvas cs:x=2cm,y=1cm) circle (2pt);` (28.45pt is about 1cm) Also, read the description of the `xyz` coordinate system in the manual, especially the last two paragraphs, starting with *Note* and *Note furthermore*.

Comment: That's what I assumed too. Points is a weird unit to me, anything non metric is for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Package `calculator` seems to make things easier:

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300,size=1080x800,outext=.png}]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usetikzlibrary{rulercompass}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,quotes,angles}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm,black!25,thin] (-1,-1) grid (5,2);
%sin(120)=0.86
\DEGREESSIN{120}{\sol}
\TRUNCATE[2]{\sol}{\sol} 
\fill[red] (canvas cs:x=0cm,y={1cm*sin(120)}) circle (2pt) 
node[label={[xshift=0.35cm]{\sol}}] {};

\fill[red] (canvas cs:x=0.2cm,y={1cm*\sol}) circle (2pt) 
node[label={[xshift=0.35cm, yshift=-0.65cm]{\sol}}] {};

\fill[red] (canvas cs:x=.4cm,y=0.86cm) circle (2pt);
%sin(90)=1
\DEGREESSIN{90}{\sol}
%\TRUNCATE[2]{\sol}{\sol} 
\fill[purple] (canvas cs:x=1cm,y={1cm*sin(90)}) circle (2pt) 
node[label={[xshift=0.35cm]{\sol}}] {};

\fill[purple] (canvas cs:x=1.2cm,y={1cm*\sol}) circle (2pt) 
node[label={[xshift=0.35cm, yshift=-0.65cm]{\sol}}] {};

%sin(45)=0.7
\DEGREESSIN{45}{\sol}
\TRUNCATE[2]{\sol}{\sol}
\fill[green] (canvas cs:x=2cm,y={1*sin(45)}) circle (2pt)
node[label={[xshift=0.35cm]{\sol}}] {};

% sin(30) = 0.5
\DEGREESSIN{30}{\sol}
\TRUNCATE[2]{\sol}{\sol}
\fill[blue] (canvas cs:x=3cm,y={1cm*sin(30)}) circle (2pt)
node[label={[xshift=-0.35cm, yshift=-0.65cm]{\sol}}] {};

\fill[black] (canvas cs:x=3cm,y={5mm+1*sin(30)}) circle (2pt)
node[label={[xshift=0.35cm]{\sol}}] {};

\fill[pink] (canvas cs:x=4cm,y={5mm+1*\sol}) circle (2pt)
node[label={[xshift=0.35cm]{\sol}}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]